# If statement in Swift 3 using OR || operator

Tags: swift, or-operator

How should I use the If statement using OR `||` operator in Swift 3

```
if (oName.text="" || oWeight.text="")
{
    print("Field Empty")

}
```

Comment: What's the question sorry? You used it

Comment: what's wrong with your code? it looks correct

Comment: I also voted to close based on a typographical error - this question doesn't really seem that helpful?

Comment: Your question is not asked as per the documentation.

Comment: You can simply use `isEmpty` property instead of that.

Comment: @NiravD as a textfield returns `String?` using `isEmpty` would need optional chaining and wouldn't be as clear and concise: `oName.text?.isEmpty ?? true || oWeight.text?.isEmpty ?? true` The above way is perfectly acceptable...

Comment: @NiravD you can write that but that goes against the whole point of optionals if you're explicitly unwrapping them... (I don't see how it being an outlet is relevant when the `text` is optional)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're assigning instead of checking for equality...

```
if (oName.text == "" || oWeight.text == "") {
    print("Field Empty")
}
```